# Can't call method "getline" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, csv

In a perl script I get the error:

> Can't call method `getline` on an undefined value

Here is part of the code. I use `Text::CSV` to read a file:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new(
    {   binary       => 1,
        encoding_in  => "iso-8859-1",
        encoding_out => "cp1252",
        sep_char     => ';'
    }
);

open my $fhandle, '<:encoding(utf8)', $fileName
    or die "Cannot use CSV:" . Text::CSV->error_diag();
while ( my $fields = $csv->getline($fhandle) ) {
    push( @array, $fields->[0] );
    push( @array, $fields->[1] );
    push( @array, $fields->[2] );
}
```

Comment: Where is `$csv` declared/assigned?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to include slightly more information. I also indented your code sample so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit the question and provide any more available information in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: I have edited your instantiation of `$csv` into the above, and reformatted the code slightly for clarity. Please can you double check that it's still correct?

Answer (score 2):

That error message specifically means the variable `$csv` is undefined.

Are you instantiating it correctly? From the documentation on [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm):

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
             or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
```

Check your code for a line that looks like this (might have different options, that doesn't matter as much).

Note that your error to `die` - is nothing to do with `Text::CSV` it's a conventional file open. Therefore:

```
die "Cannot use CSV:".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
```

Is misleading. It will still error if your `open` fails, but it won't report the problem correctly. You should instead:

```
die "Error opening file: $!";
```

Edit: From comments you are using:

```
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({binary => 1, encoding_in => "iso-8859-1", encoding_out => "cp1252", sep_char => ';'});
```

Try changing that to:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new(
    {   binary       => 1,
        encoding_in  => "iso-8859-1",
        encoding_out => "cp1252",
        sep_char     => ';'
    }
) or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();
```

And you will get the following error:

```
Cannot use CSV: INI - Unknown attribute 'encoding_in' at line 2.
```

You therefore don't successfully instantiate your `$csv` object, which is why you get an error.

The code you're referring to in `Text::CSV` looks like this:

```
use Text::CSV::Encoded;
my $csv = Text::CSV::Encoded->new ({
    encoding_in  => "iso-8859-1", # the encoding comes into   Perl
    encoding_out => "cp1252",     # the encoding comes out of Perl
});
```

E.g. uses a different module - [`Text::CSV::Encoded`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-Encoded-0.22/lib/Text/CSV/Encoded.pm)

Comment: OK. Trap the error from that, because that's failing.

Comment: the variable $csv is defined like this

Comment: Edited answer. This is your problem: `Cannot use CSV:INI - Unknown attribute 'encoding_out'`. You need to use `http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-Encoded-0.22/lib/Text/CSV/Encoded.pm`

Comment: my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({binary => 1,                      
                           encoding_in  => "iso-8859-1", 
                           encoding_out => "cp1252",
                           sep_char => ';'});

Comment: If you have another question, then it's worth asking separately.

Answer (score 2):

A bad open() caused the getline error

Modified:

```
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
}
```

as substituting $file for "test.csv" created the issue.

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({binary=>1}) ;
$file = "test.csv" ;
if(!open($fh, "<", $file )) {
  # Cannot call getline is a symptom of a bad open() 
  printf("### Error %s: could not open file %s\n", $ws, $file) ;
  close($fh) ;
  exit 1 ; 
}
while(my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  @items = @{$row} ;
  for(my $i=0 ; $i<=$#items; $i++) {
    printf("Field %d: (%s)\n", $i, $items[$i] ) ;
  }
}
```